# get json data from a public json file not REST api with React

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, fetch

I have a url similar to https://www.nonexistentsite.com/fubar.json where fubar.json is a public json file which will download to your file system if you navigate to the url with your browser. I have a React web app where I want to read that file directly so as to display some of its data. I don't want to bother with any kind of a backend that would download the file to the apps file system so that it can read it. I want the React front end to read it directly in it's client side code with a fetch or an axios call or something like that. I'm familiar with the typical situation where I have a REST url like https://www.nonexistentsite.com/fubar which I can call and get the data. I'm failing to find info on how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to load the data from the json file.

Example usage;

```
axios.get('https://www.nonexistentsite.com/fubar.json')
.then(jsoncontent => {
  console.log(jsoncontent);
  //do stuff with jsoncontent here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but I believe if you are just needing to fetch the json from a hosted file, you should be able to do so with axios.get(url)